# Umbraco 5 and asp.net MVC

Tags: umbraco

I've heard that the approaching umbraco 5 i going to be based on asp.net MVC. Does it mean that the developers will have to be familiar with the MVC? Will you please tell me what the exact meaning of being "based on MVC"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means exactly what it says: Umbraco 5 will be an ASP.NET MVC3 application instead of being a webforms application.

This indeed means that your developers will soon need to be familiar with MVC, although, it is quite feasable that most of the Razor concepts are already known to your developers.

If you have more specific questions, don't hesitate to post them. A better area would be http://our.umbraco.org though, the community is quite large and much more responsive there than on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3):

Umbraco 5 has been cancelled.  Fortunately, a small team of developers has decided to fork the project:

http://www.rebelcms.com/

Answer (score 0):

This is very intesting stuff about Umbraco 5, as I know Sitecore, for example, should include support of MVC as well. But they will support both variants for developers ASP.NET and ASP MVC. That from my point of view much better. May be Umbraco 5 will be have the same